# How to calculate the extended perimeter of a polygon from a specified convex polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons, convex-hulls

I am currently given points in the 2D plane. From which I created a convex Hull. Now I need to cover this convex hull with a polygon, but the distance between the points of convex hull and the extended polygon should be at least L or simply we can say the extended polygon should be at least L distance away from every point in the convex hull. Also, we need to minimize the perimeter of the extended polygon.
I came across a solution that said

$Ans = perimeter\ of\ convex\ Hull\ +\ 2*\pi*L$

Can anyone explain what this above solution means and how it was evaluated?

The problem link is [this](https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the quadrilateral $ABCD$ as an example of a convex polygon. The locus of points a fixed distance $l$ from the outside of $ABCD$ is drawn below. This shape is the furthest away a polygon can be away from the original polygon and the perimeter of this shape is an upper bound for the perimeter for any extended convex polygon.

[image]

It is obvious that lengths $AD=LE$, $DC=FG$, $CB=HJ$ and $BA=IK$, so the perimeter of this shape is the perimeter of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ together with the arcs $EF$, $GH$, $JI$ and $KL$. These arcs form a circle if added together, with perimeter $2 \pi l$, which gives the answer to your question.

Comment: Wow! They form a circle. Thanks for the help btw is there any standard result related to this formation of circle ?

Comment: Usually this is studied under the topic of "locus" (plural "loci") in geometry.